# Repair Top of Stud

Tags: studs

I was drilling a hole through the top plate in the attic for Ethernet conduit and got too close to a non load bearing stud for the room below.  The hole saw got the head of a nail and left a gap that leaves the wall cavity below visible.  The hole through the top of the stud looks to be centered on the 4" edge  The wall is finished with drywall on both sides and this is old construction. I'm looking to fill in the hole if only for preventing air flow from the attic and re-secure the stud to the top plate since I would like to arm mount a 26inch tv to the stud because of course its going to be the one I nicked.

What are my options for repair and do I need to be concerned putting a load on it?

[image: inside hole top plate]

[image: stud from side]

Comment: Welcome to DIY Stack Exchange. Here the old adage "a picture is worth a thousand words" applies. Maybe you could post some pictures of the damage. Go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to see how to post pictures.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't look like you can fit your conduit through there. I would not worry about any kind of stud repair and just move over 2 inches and drill another hole.

Comment: An arm mount for a tv will put a significant cantilever stress on that stud. If the top of the stud is held in line, the stud could rotate and fail, (even with a wall finish on both sides of wall). Is there any nail(s) holding this stud to the top plate?    How big is that hole through that top plate? That could cause the wall to fail too, when the arm mount tv is installed, even though, as you say, "it's a non load bearing wall."

Comment: I edited the first post and removed my comment due to new information. A view of the side I damaged shows two more nails leading me to believe 5 were used (2/3).  Would adding a tie plate for additional support be recommended?